# Madri killed by Apocalypse himself

Tags: marvel, x-men

There's a comic in the Age of Apocalypse called *The chosen*, where a Madri goes into the computer of Apocalypse in order to know if the Madri are chosen or forgotten. It says at the second page of the issue: "But only **one** of the Madri would dare access his most classified data".

I knew that the Madri were replicas of Madrox, is there something special about this gossip Madri, or just someone put there without reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as we can tell, no. By using the phrase "But only **one** of the Madri would dare access his most classified data", I believe that it was meant to convey that Apocalypse viewed this particular Madri as either un-loyal or insane to his cause, which was punishable by death, regardless of who you were.

Comment: Just thought I'd check, is there anything else I could add to improve upon this answer?

Comment: No, it was a fine answer :)